# What is this code doing? (Creating C-style array of NSPoints)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
NSArray *objects = ... // array of objects with a coordinate
unsigned int count = [objects count];
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:count*sizeof(NSPoint)];
NSPoint *points = (NSPoint*)[data bytes];
unsigned int i;
[data retain];
for (i=0; i<[objects count]; i++) {
    points[i] = [[objects objectAtIndex:i] coordinate];
}
[data release];
```

What is this code doing?
Why does it multiply `count*sizeof(nspoint)`?
What is the `NSPoint` struct?

Answer (score 5):

`NSPoint` is the Cocoa (Mac OS X) structure representing a 2-D coordinate.  It is the same as `CGPoint`.

This program creates a C-style array of `NSPoint`s.  The array is stored in the memory managed by an `NSMutableData` object.  Since the array has `objects.count` elements, and each element is an `NSPoint`, he asks the `NSMutableData` to allocate `objects.count * sizeof(NSPoint)` bytes of memory.

Comment: so why do i use nspoint?

Comment: I don't know why you use `NSPoint`.  Why did you choose to use `NSPoint`?

Comment: no no ,i ask what is nspoint struct do?

Comment: I told you.  An `NSPoint` represents a 2-D coordinate.  It is the same as `CGPoint`.

Comment: If you want to know why the author of that code used `NSPoint` instead of `CGPoint`, ask the author of that code.  It might have been written before the name `CGPoint` was invented.  The name `NSPoint` is older than the name `CGPoint`.

Comment: Further to Rob's explanation the C array is created from an Obj-C array of objects each of which has a method `coordinate` which returns a value of type `NSPoint`. @Mohamed: the struct doesn't "do" anything, it is used to represent a point in 2-D space as Rob stated.